# When converting a layer to a KML file, the Name field is not being used for the pop-up title in Google Earth

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, kml, google-earth, layer-to-kml

I'm using Arc Map 10.7 to create a KML that shows point data representing milepoints along a bunch of roadways. I want the pop-up when you click one of those points to display the milepoint number as the title of the pop-up.

According to ESRI documentation, the title should default to any field named "Name" as long as there are no labels active on the layer in Arc Map. I added a new field to the layer, named it "Name", made it a text field, and used field calculator to populate it with "Mileage " + [milepoint field]. Then I converted the layer to KML using the layer-to-kml tool. I tested it on a shapefile a while back and it worked fine, but for this file the title is still the [Route_ID] field. There are no extra characters and I even moved it all the way to the top of the fields list in properties.

Does anyone know of another reason the KML will not pick up my "name" field as the pop-up title?

Answer (score 0):

Using ArcMap 10.5.1, I was able to adjust the KML feature title by changing the Label Field (Layer Properties --> Labels) to whatever you want to be the output. Not sure if the layer needs labeling turned on before the conversion, but that worked for me.